# Загрузка постов при клике WordPress

Tags: php, html, css, ajax, wordpress

Вот JS

```
(function($) {
    $('.pages_list a').click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        postId = $(this).attr('data-catid');
        $.ajax({
            url: "/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php",
            method: 'post',
            data: {
                action: 'ajax_order',
                name: postId,
                countpost: '<? echo get_field("count_publications"); ?>'
            },
        success: function (response) {
            $("#thumbs").html(response);
           }
        });
    });
}(jQuery));
```

Этот код берет значение id рубрики постов

```
postId = $(this).attr('data-catid');
```

Вот код в functions.php

```
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_ajax_order', 'ajax_form' );
add_action('wp_ajax_ajax_order', 'ajax_form' );

function ajax_form(){
    $postId = $_REQUEST['name'];
    $countPublications = $_REQUEST['countpost'];
    if ( defined( 'DOING_AJAX' ) && DOING_AJAX ){           
        $paged = get_query_var( 'paged', $postId );
        $recent = new WP_Query("cat=$postId&showposts=$countPublications&paged=$paged");
        $postArr = array();
        while($recent->have_posts()) : $recent->the_post();
            $link = get_the_permalink();
            $title = get_the_title();
            if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) {
                $image = get_the_post_thumbnail('miniatures');
            } else {
                $imagePath = bloginfo("template_url") . "/img/no_image.jpg";
                $image = '<img src='.$imagePath.' alt="'.$title.'"/>';
            }
            $thumbDesc = get_the_excerpt();     
            $postItem = '<a href='.$postId.' alt='.$title.' rel="bookmark" class="thumb_3"><div class="img-box">'.$image.'</div><h4>'.$title.'</h4>'.$thumbDesc.'</a>';
            array_push($postArr, $postItem);
        endwhile;
        wp_reset_postdata();
        echo $postArr;
        wp_die();
    }
}
```

Этот JS

```
$("#thumbs").html(response);
```

Выводит пустой массив, а не массив с HTML постов. Как вывести массив постов при клике ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_ajax_order', 'ajax_form' );
    add_action('wp_ajax_ajax_order', 'ajax_form' );
    function ajax_form(){
        $postId = $_REQUEST['name'];
        $countPublications = $_REQUEST['countpost'];
        if ( defined( 'DOING_AJAX' ) && DOING_AJAX ){           
            // $paged = get_query_var('paged', $postId);
            $recent = new WP_Query(array('cat'=>$postId));
            $postArr = array();
            while($recent->have_posts()) : $recent->the_post();
                $link = get_permalink();
                $title = get_the_title();
                $postContentId = get_the_ID();
                if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) {
                    $image = get_the_post_thumbnail( $id, 'miniatures', array('class' => 'alignleft') );
                } else {
                    $imagePath = get_bloginfo("template_url") . "/img/no_image.jpg";
                    $image = '<img src='.$imagePath.' alt="'.$title.'"/>';
                }
                $thumbDesc = get_the_excerpt();
                $postItem = '<a href='.$postId.' alt='.$title.' data-postid='.$postContentId.' rel="bookmark" class="thumb_3"><div class="img-box">'.$image.'</div><h4>'.$title.'</h4>'.$thumbDesc.'</a>';
                array_push($postArr, $postItem);
            endwhile;
            wp_reset_postdata();
            echo "<div class='thumbnails_3 thumbnails_3_2 offset_ziro'>".implode('', $postArr)."</div>";
            wp_die();
        }
    }
```